# Django static files organization

Tags: django

I'm working in new app in Django and I researching for the best way to organize my project. At this moment each app will be an independent module for my system, each one will have their own models, templates, urls, etc..
but now I just confuse about how to set my static files.

If I create a new folder static for each app (which actually is an option) I may have to import from other apps.

What I really want to do is keep inside the app just the files for the app, in special JavaScript, and keep plugins and frameworks like jQuery and React.js for global usage.

```
project_name
- app
  - migrations
  ...
  - static (just app js)
    - js
  - templates
    - item.html
    - list.html
- project_name
- static (global)
    - plugins
        - jQuery
        - bootstrap
        - react
    - css 
        - sass
    - js 
        - elements
        - components
    - img
- __init__.py
- manage.py
```

Would be a good idea to make something like this? How would be the best way to organize this folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done both in numerous projects, I find the best way to do this is put everything in one spot. Just keep them all in the top level static folder. That way all of them are in one place and you (or another dev) don't have to go searching all over the project if you're trying to find a particular file. Same principle applies to templates. If a designer needs access to templates to do some work they will be thankful they're not scattered all over the place. The only case in which the above wouldn't apply is when you're making a portable app.

Comment: In this situation you are splitting your website  pages in several apps or using a single app with several views?

Comment: this would be a typical Django project with multiple apps, but with top level `static` and `templates` folders by setting `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `TEMAPLTES['DIRS']`, respectively